# Security Settings Problems in testing Flash 8 Application

Tags: security, flash

I designed a multiple quiz application that needs comunicate with php files in a remote (free) server, when try to run it (the swf file) a popup windows asks me to set security settings and takes me to the Adobe page http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04a.html
After reading it, I put the path of my swf file in the trusted box and then refresh the application but the same popup message !!! , why?.
My application was designed with Macromedia Flash Professional 8 in Windows XP. When I run the code from Macromedia Flash 8, no problem.

:(

Comment: I was trying with : C:\mch.swf , C:/mch.swf  ,  C:\mch.swf\ and if I use the browser button to find the path, it's written ///0/mch.swf . I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I autosolved my own question hehe, I went to Control Panel ---> Flash Player and added the corresponding files, everything went OK. And I have published my flash html file. By the way, if you think to do that in Google sites, flash apparently in not allowed to communicate to php file , google policy I think.